# How can you calculate the probability of failure of a product after a given time, given the expected failures per unit time?

Tags: statistics

For example, if a product has an expected failure rate of 1 failure every 10 years of operation, what's the probability that the product fails after 1 year of use? How does this probability change if we ask the same question, but now we are using 2 of the same product in parallel? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) to model this type of problem. Let $t$ be a random variable with distribution $t \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$. Here, $t$ represents the amount of time to failure, and $\lambda$ is the rate parameter, where $E[t] = \frac{1}{\lambda}$. Then, we have the following cumulative distribution function:

$$ P[t < T] = 1 - e^{-\lambda T} . $$

We're given that the expected failure rate is $1$ failure in $10$ years of operation. Interpreting that as the mean time to failure, we have $\lambda = \frac{1}{10}$. Plugging in $\lambda$, we have

$$ P[t < T] = 1 - e^{-\frac{T}{10}} . $$

The probability that the product fails within $T = 1$ year is

$$ P[t < 1] = 1 - e^{-\frac{1}{10}} \approx 9.5 \% . $$

Now, let's say we have $n$ of these products running in parallel, and we can assume that the failure of any one product is independent of the failure of any other products. Let $t_i$ represent the time to failure of the $i$th product, where each $t_i$ is independently and identically distributed the same way as $t$ above.

**Probability of at Least One Failure**

If we want the probability that at least one of the products fails within time T, we're looking for

$$ P[t_1 < T \cup t_2 < T \cup \ ... \ \cup t_n < T] . $$

This isn't a particularly easy way to frame this calculation - we'd have to calculate the probability of exactly one of them failing, or exactly two of them failing, etc., and we'd have to account for all possible combinations of products. But, there's a way to reframe it that's a lot easier.

The complement of the event that at least one product fails is that none of the products fail. In that case, we have

$$ P[t_1 < T \cup t_2 < T \cup \ ... \ \cup t_n < T] = 1 - P[t_1 > T \cap t_2 > T \cap \ ... \ \cap t_n > T] . $$

Since we assumed these failures were independent, we have

$$ 1 - P[t_1 > T \cap t_2 > T \cap \ ... \ \cap t_n > T] $$
$$ = 1 - P[t_1 > T]* P[t_2 > T]* \ ... \ *P[t_n > T] $$
$$ = 1 - (P[t > T])^n $$
$$ = 1 - (1 - P[t < T])^n $$
$$ = 1 - \left(1 - \left(1 - e^{-\frac{T}{10}} \right) \right)^n $$
$$ = 1 - \left(e^{-\frac{T}{10}} \right)^n $$
$$ = 1 - e^{-\frac{nT}{10}} . $$

When $n = 2$ and $T = 1$, we have

$$ P[t_1 < 1 \cup t_2 < 1] = 1 - e^{-\frac{2*1}{10}} \approx 18.1 \%. $$

**Probability of $n$ Failures**

Now, if we want to find the probability that all $n$ products fail within time $T$, we want

$$ P[t_1 < T \cap t_2 < T \cap \ ... \ \cap t_n < T] . $$

Again, through independence, we can split this up into individual probabilities and calculate:

$$ P[t_1 < T \cap t_2 < T \cap \ ... \ \cap t_n < T] $$
$$ = P[t_1 < T]*P[t_2 < T]* \ ... \ *P[t_n < T] $$
$$ = (P[t < T])^n $$
$$ = \left(1-e^{-\frac{T}{10}}\right)^n . $$

For $n = 2$ and $T = 1$, we have

$$ P[t_1 < 1 \cap t_2 < 1] = \left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{10}}\right)^2 $$
$$ \approx 0.9 \% . $$

Comment: So this means the probability of a product failing in 10 years or less is 1 - (1/e) or about 63%. Intuitively, I would think that if a product is expected to fail in 10 years, that half the products would fail before 10 years, and half the products would fail after 10 years. Is there an intuitive reason to explain why nearly 2 thirds of products fail before the mean-time-to-failure? Am I correct in interpreting that ~63% of all products in general will fail before their MTTF?

Comment: The shape of this model is based on the assumption that the rate of failure is constant over time, that forces it to look like an exponential decay function. It lets you use the same rate parameter for all $t$. But, because of that shape, the distribution isn't symmetric, and you end up with the mean and median not being the same value, and that's why it isn't a $50 \%$ probability of failure at $10$ years.